# Qt: Read persian text from a utf-8 text file

Tags: qt, utf-8

This is my code:

```
QByteArray a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,i2,j2;
QString  a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1,g1,h1,i1,j1;    
QFile m("D:/t.dat");
m.open(QFile :: ReadOnly | QFile :: Text );
QTextStream ot1(&m);
ot1 >> a2 >> b2 >> c2 >> d2 >> e2 >> f2 >> g2 >> h2 >> i2 >> j2;
m.close();

QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8");
a1 = codec->toUnicode(a2);
b1 = codec->toUnicode(b2);
c1 = codec->toUnicode(c2);
d1 = codec->toUnicode(d2);
e1 = codec->toUnicode(e2);
f1 = codec->toUnicode(f2);
g1 = codec->toUnicode(g2);
h1 = codec->toUnicode(h2);
i1 = codec->toUnicode(i2);
j1 = codec->toUnicode(j2);
//set labels
ui->label_12->setText(a1);
ui->label_13->setText(b1);
ui->label_14->setText(c1);
ui->label_15->setText(d1);
ui->label_16->setText(e1);
ui->label_17->setText(f1);
ui->label_18->setText(g1);
ui->label_19->setText(h1);
ui->label_20->setText(i1);
ui->label_21->setText(j1);
```

In text file:

> 1 2 صادق بیکی 2 5 77 یزد محمد مرد

At first, program read persian (Farsi) text from t.txt . At middle convert them to QString.
This code can convert UTF-8 to QString, but some of the characters like "ق" or "ی" convert to "?". Why?

This is a photo of program: http://www.upsara.com/images/2dsg_capture.png

Comment: Are you sure those characters exist in the font being used?

Comment: Yes , I,m sure. You can see the text and photo